# Journey planning

Tags: algorithm

> If you have the full bus schedule for a country, how can you find out the maximum number of people that can be carried between between two specified stops in 1 day?

I assume a bus schedule gives you the full list of leaving and arriving times for every bus stop and also the capacity of each bus.   You are given the start and end stop in the question.

You could determine a sequence of buses that gives the shortest time to the destination and fill up all the buses that leave from the start going along this path and then when each bus arrives at a stop, just transfer as many passengers as possible to the next bus that is leaving.  There is no reason why this should have maximal capacity however.

What is the fastest this problem can be solved?  For example, suppose that for M cities I'm given a total of N records; route record Rᵢ contains a number Kᵢ, a capacity Cᵢ, and lists of Kᵢ city numbers, Kᵢ arrival times, and Kᵢ departure times. (The first arrival time and the last departure time in  Rᵢ are irrelevant.)  Can a breadth-first search program solve the question in O(M*N) time?

Comment: Do you have a programming question?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The question are quite different. The other question talks about the maximum distance you can travel between *any* two nodes and this question is about the maximum *capacity* between two *specified* nodes. I don't expect the solutions to be similar either.

Comment: Fair enough, we do however still need a programming question

Comment: @felix: What data do we have about the passengers?

Comment: Are the "Maximum Capacity" ratings for buses strictly adhered to in the country for which you have a bus schedule? Just sayin.... 'cuz there are some countries where I do *not* want to ride the buses...

Comment: This is obviously not a duplicate of the other question.  It's a max-flow variant of a shortest path problem.

Comment: Where are you finding these questions?

Comment: @SaviourSelf I love buses :)  (I actually just think they are interesting algorithmic problems whose solutions I would like to implement.)

Comment: well, please correct me if I'm wrong. If I know the bus schedule then what I've to do except simulate this schedule? Just simulating the schedule will give me the number of people carried from stoppage A to stoppage B and that result will be unique.

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet From a given stop there may be buses to lots of places. You have to choose how many passengers to put on each bus.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed when it has been established it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I doubt that the general question has a precise solution.  One can obviously make a number of educated guesses, and/or simulate it in a number of ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a weird puzzle; it's an algorithms question. One way to solve this is to make a directed graph with a node for every (location, arrival time) and (location, departure time). Each arrival node has an infinite capacity arc to all departures at the same location that aren't earlier. Each departure node has an arc to each of the appropriate arrival nodes (per the bus schedule), weighted with the capacity of the bus. Then you can use your favorite algorithm to find the maximum flow from your source to your sink.

Your source node should be an arrival node at time zero at your start location, your sink node should be a departure node at the ending time at your ending location.

Comment: The complexity is horrible but maybe that's as good as it gets.

Comment: You could do a first pass to prune useless nodes from the graph. E.g., time-weight the graph and use Dijkstra from the source and sink, deleting any nodes where the source+sink time > 24 hours. That may or may not be useful, depending on what your graph looks like.